# JavaFX play local video with whitespace in a path

Tags: javafx-2

I'm building a small application, that can play video, the problem, that when I add a video with a whitespace in it's path - it gives me an error:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 13: FILE:C:/Video menu/video/03.mp4
```

Here's my scene:

```
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 1024, Color.BLACK);
    String path = new String("FILE:C:/Video menu/touchMV/03.mp4");
    URI uri = new URI(path);
    root.getChildren().add(
            MediaViewBuilder.create()
                    .mediaPlayer(
                            MediaPlayerBuilder.create()
                            .media(
                                    new Media(
                                            path
                                    )

                            ).build()
                    ).build()
    );


    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
```

The `Media(java.lang.String source)` docs said that it have Constraints:

- The supplied URI must conform to RFC-2396 as required by java.net.URI.
- Only HTTP, FILE, and JAR URIs are supported.

I tried to pass a Media() constructor an `(new URI(path)).toString();` and `(new URI(path)).toASCIIString()` it didn't worked. Changing a whitespace to `%20` didn't worked as well.

What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know the cause of your problem, but it works if you create a `File` first and call `File#toURI#toASCIIString`.

```
 File file = new File("C:\\Video menu\\touchMV\\03.mp4");
 String path = file.toURI().toASCIIString();
```